# Unable to convert class component to function component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

This is how semantic-ui menu component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Input, Menu, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class MenuExamplePointing extends Component {
  state = { activeItem: 'home' }

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <Menu pointing>
          <Menu.Item
            name='home'
            active={activeItem === 'home'}
            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            name='messages'
            active={activeItem === 'messages'}
            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            name='friends'
            active={activeItem === 'friends'}
            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
          />
          <Menu.Menu position='right'>
            <Menu.Item>
              <Input icon='search' placeholder='Search...' />
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu.Menu>
        </Menu>

        <Segment>
          <img src='https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png' />
        </Segment>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am trying to convert this into function component. This is how my function component looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Menu, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";

function App() {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("home");

  const setActiveItemOnClick = e => {
    alert(e.target.name);
    setActiveItem(e.target.name);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Menu pointing>
        <Menu.Item
          name="home"
          active={activeItem === "home"}
          onClick={setActiveItemOnClick}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name="messages"
          active={activeItem === "messages"}
          onClick={setActiveItemOnClick}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name="friends"
          active={activeItem === "friends"}
          onClick={setActiveItemOnClick}
        />
      </Menu>

      <Segment>
        <img src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
      </Segment>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This works fine for the most part except that when I click on the menu item, `e.target.name` is empty.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fixed code

```
function App() {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("home");

  const setActiveItemOnClick = (e, { name }) => {
    console.log(name);
    setActiveItem(name);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MenuExamplePointing />
      <Menu pointing>
        <Menu.Item
          name="home"
          active={activeItem === "home"}
          onClick={setActiveItemOnClick}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name="messages"
          active={activeItem === "messages"}
          onClick={setActiveItemOnClick}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name="friends"
          active={activeItem === "friends"}
          onClick={setActiveItemOnClick}
        />
      </Menu>

      <Segment>
        <img src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
      </Segment>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your class component you are destructuring the second parameter of handleItemClick

```
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })
                          ^
```

You can do the same for your handler in your functional component

```
const setActiveItemOnClick = (e, { name }) => {
  console.log(name);
  setActiveItem(name);
};
```

If you take a look at the DOM, the `name` prop doesn't get passed forward
[image: itemList DoM]

therefore it is not accessibleby e.target
if you take a look at the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/) of the Menu.item component,
you can see that the original props that were sent to the Menu.item component are accessible from the `data` prop of the onClick function

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and I found this: e.target doesn't contain an attribute called name. so I think you should do something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Menu, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";

function App() {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("home");

  const setActiveItemOnClick = (name) => {

    setActiveItem(name);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Menu pointing>
        <Menu.Item
          name="home"
          active={activeItem === "home"}
          onClick={() => setActiveItemOnClick("home")}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name="messages"
          active={activeItem === "messages"}
          onClick={() => setActiveItemOnClick("messages")}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name="friends"
          active={activeItem === "friends"}
          onClick={() => setActiveItemOnClick("friends")}
        />
      </Menu>

      <Segment>
        <img src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
      </Segment>
    </div>[enter image description here][1]
  );
}
export default App
```

the Menu.Item Component in react-semantic-ui creates an anchor, but it doesn't apply the name prop as an attribute to that anchor.